# Is it possible to be in try-it-out mode by default in Swagger 2?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am using Swagger 2 with Springfox.

When you click on an endpoint, is there any way to have the Try-it-out mode activated by default, without having to click this button:

[image]

Comment: There is a ticket open to enable the development mode: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2805

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6528), the option is available with **Swagger 3** => [Demo](https://petstore.swagger.io/?tryItOutEnabled=true)

Answer (score 13):

try this:
use on startup.cs (.net5) or program.cs (.net6)

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{       
    options.EnableTryItOutByDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set **TRY_IT_OUT_ENABLED=true** to enable "Try it out mode" by default.

So try to search [this option](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/) for your UI swagger lib.

In my case I use *@nestjs/swagger* package so I used the following code to enable the mode:

```
SwaggerModule.setup(apiPrefix, app, document, {
    swaggerOptions: {
        tryItOutEnabled: true,
    },
});
```

Also it works for swagger-ui package you can find [its config here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#display)